# Web service that accepts SMTP, not HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Is there any way with ASP.NET to create a web service that accepts SMTP, rather than HTTP/HTTPS?

I want to create a web service that relays an SMTP request to a fake SMTP server for testing.

Details: I help maintain a website that has to send out email notifications sometimes.  It sends the emails via an SMTP server.  We developers do not have access to an SMTP server for testing.  Currently the only way to test the email notifications is to deploy the updated website to the QA environment, a process that takes 12-15 minutes, so iterating on changes is a very slow process.  I'm looking to speed things up by using [Debug Mail](https://debugmail.io), which provides fake SMTP servers for testing (ie it doesn't actually send the email it receives, instead it just displays it on its website).

The only problem is the actual SMTP servers used by the website in QA, UAT and production do not require credentials, so the email notification code in the website doesn't handle authentication to the SMTP server.  And Debug Mail fake SMTP servers do require authentication.  So what I would like to do is create a web service that acts as a relay, accepting SMTP requests from the website and forwarding them to Debug Mail.  The web service would handle authenticating to Debug Mail.

I haven't been able to find any information online about whether this is possible in ASP.NET.  Infuriatingly, both Google and Bing think a search phrase like "asp.net web service accepting smtp" means I want to *send* emails to an SMTP server, rather than accept them.

Comment: https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev

Comment: @Martheen: That looks perfect as a fake SMTP server, no need for a relay.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think you're in a better position to post a self-answer with example code etc. I'm using Mailtrap and this library was one of the self-hosting alternatives but never got around to actually testing it.